# Testing auxiliary classes in an Angular project

Tags: angular, unit-testing

In my Angular project, along with the component classes there are auxiliary classes for data model representation, some data iterators, etc.

Angular generates test classes for components, and their names are like `component-name.component.spec.ts`

My question, what is the best approach to handle unit-tests for auxiliary classes (not component classes), to run these tests along with the rest of all tests upon testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I correctly understand your question but what I do is I follow the same convention.

```
car.service.ts + car.service.spec.ts

car-utilities.ts + car-utilities.spec.ts
```

The **karma/jest** configuration will look for ***.spec.ts** files in your src folder and it will run all of them.